# Typescript Object is of Type Unknown, firebase functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, function

I have a problem with a function for firebase functions, written in typescript.

first I have some background info:

the data structure of the /tokens ref of the realtime database:

```
Tokens: [
     TOKENS_ID: {
           token: String
},
]
```

the following code is giving me compiling errors:

```
export const onBlogPost = functions.database.ref("/blogs/{bid}")
.onCreate((blogData) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(blogData.val()));
  admin.database().ref("/tokens").once("value")
      .then((snapshot) => {
        const data = snapshot.val();
        const tokens = Object.values(data).map((value) => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(value));
          const token = value.token;
          return token;
        });
        return console.log(JSON.stringify(tokens));
      });
});
```

The problem is within the `.then((snapshot) => {...}` part. the goal of this part of the code is to transform all the objects within the data snapshot to a single array of just the tokens.

the compiling error occurs on the row with the following code:

```
const token = value.token;
```

the compiling error is as follows:

```
src/index.ts(14,29): error TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'.
```

What is the correct solution to this, I have tried to assign a type to the variable value in `map()` but that was failing horendesly.

Answer (score 1):

force the type as:

```
const token: string = value.token;
```

or

```
const token = value.token as string;
```

Comment: I have tried both, but none of them seems to work

Comment: then force to parse the value as: `const token: string = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value.token))`. This must work.